# Dokku and bitbucket ci/cd

Tags: bitbucket, continuous-deployment, bitbucket-pipelines, dokku

Is there simple receipt how to integrate bitbucket pipeline with dokku?
I want to continuously deploy to production server after commit in master

Answer (score 1):

The necessary steps can be boiled down to:

- Enable pipelines.
- Generate an SSH key for the pipelines script and [add it to dokku](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/deployment/user-management/#adding-ssh-keys).
- Add the dokku host as a known host in pipelines.
- If you're using private dependencies, also add bitbucket.org as a known host.
- Define the environment variable DOKKU_REMOTE_URL.
- Use a bitbucket-pipelines.yml file (see example below).

The easy way is to manage it directly from your app's root folder.
Create a `bitbucket-pipelines.yml` file in which we enter something like the following:

```
image: node:8.9.4

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        caches:
          - node
        script:
          # Add SSH keys for private dependencies
          - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
          - echo $SSH_KEY | base64 -d > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
          - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

          # Install and run checks
          - curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash -s -- --version 1.3.2
          - export PATH=$HOME/.yarn/bin:$PATH
          - yarn install # Build is triggered from the postinstall hook

  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            # Add SSH keys for deployment
            - mkdir -p ~/.ssh
            - echo $SSH_KEY | base64 -d > ~/.ssh/id_rsa
            - chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_rsa

            # Deploy to hosting
            - git remote add dokku $DOKKU_REMOTE_URL
            - git push dokku master
```

Remember dokku takes care of `npm install` so all we have to do is setup the docker instance (running in bitbucket) for deploying to dokku.

However pay attention to the `image: node:8.9.4`, as it is generally a good idea to enforce an image that uses the *exact* version of node (or whichever language), that you use in your application.

Steps 2-4 is just fidgetting around with the settings in Bitbuckets Repository Settings --> Pipelines --> SSH keys, where you will generate an SSH key, add it to your dokku installation.
For the known host you want to enter the IP adress (or domain name) of the server hosting your dokku installation, and press fetch, followed by add host.

See this example application: https://github.com/amannn/dokku-node-hello-world#continuous-deployment-from-bitbucket.